# How to separate nested async functions and execute them in a desired order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, async-await, puppeteer

I have an async function which takes the list of URLs as the value from a parsed csv file.
Inside this function, I use puppeteer to launch a page and navigate to each url.
I have two functions- one to download the resources and another to check if the resource was downloaded.

1. I would like to run *scriptDownload()* first and after it's execution is finished, run *networkProfile()* function.
2. I would also like to know if these functions can be isolated in a separate file and apply the functionality of module exports and imports.

I have not initialized the functions in the code attached.

Also, there would be few async mongodb commands that would be added later in *networkProfile()*.

I had tried using *.then* but didn't work out. Always *networkProfile()* runs before *scriptDownload()*

Also tried exporting these functions as separate modules- but resulted in error- *page- unidentified reference*

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var fse = require('fs-extra');
var Papa= require("papaparse");
const path = require('path');
var scr = require('./scripts');

async function scripts(x){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
        headless: true,
        args: ['--enable-features=NetworkService'],
        ignoreHTTPSErrors:true
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    await client.send('Network.enable');
    await client.send('Network.clearBrowserCache');
    await client.send('Runtime.enable');
    await client.send('Debugger.enable');

    async function scriptDownload() {

        page.on('response', async resp => {
            const url = new URL(page.url()).host;
            const url1 = resp.request().url();
            var url2 = path.basename(url1);
            url2 = url2.replace(/\?/g, '&q');
            const isScript = resp.request().resourceType() === 'script';
            const isCSS = resp.request().resourceType() === 'stylesheet';
            const isXHR = resp.request().resourceType() === 'xhr';

            if (isScript) {
                let filePath = path.resolve(`./Responses/${url}/js/${url2}.js`);
                await fse.outputFile(filePath, await resp.text());
                console.log('Scripts Downloaded');
            }
            if (isCSS) {
                let filePath = path.resolve(`./Responses/${url}/css/${url2}.css`);
                await fse.outputFileSync(filePath, await resp.text());
                console.log('CSS Downloaded');
            }
            if (isXHR) {
                let filePath = path.resolve(`./Responses/${url}/xhr/${url2}.xhr`);
                await fse.outputFileSync(filePath, await resp.text());
                console.log('XHR Downloaded');
            }
        });
    }

    //network domian
    async function networkProfile() {
        client.on('Network.requestWillBeSent', parameters => {
            const request_url = parameters.request.url;
            var reqname = path.basename(request_url);
            var reqnamereg = reqname.replace(/\?/g, '&q');
            const urlloc = new URL(page.url()).host;
            try {
                    /**************************Check if file exists********************************************************** */
                    const jsFilePath = path.resolve(`./Responses/${urlloc}/js/${reqnamereg}.js`);
                    const jsPath = path.resolve(`./Responses/${urlloc}/js/${reqnamereg}`);
                    var locStorage = "null";

                    async function localjs(f) {
                        const existsjs = await fse.pathExists(f)
                        if (existsjs == true) {
                            locStorage = jsPath;
                            console.log(urlloc, reqnamereg, existsjs);
                        }
                        else {
                            locStorage = 'Js does not exist';
                            console.log(urlloc, reqnamereg, existsjs);
                        }
                    }

                    async function local(f) {
                        const exists = await fse.pathExists(f)
                        if (exists == true) {
                            locStorage = jsFilePath;
                            console.log(urlloc, reqname, exists);
                        }
                        else {
                            locStorage = 'File does not exist';
                            console.log(urlloc, reqname, exists);
                        }
                    }
                    if (reqname.endsWith('.js') == 'true') {
                        localjs(jsPath)
                    }
                    else {
                        local(jsFilePath)
                    }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }


    for (var j = 0; j < x.length; j++){
        try{
            await page.goto('https://www.' + x[j][1], { waitUntil: 'load' });
            const url = new URL(page.url()).host;
            let filePathhtml = path.resolve(`./Responses/${url}/html/${url}.html`);
            await fse.outputFileSync(filePathhtml, await page.content());
        }
        catch(error){
            if(error==='net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT'){
            }
        }
    }

    setTimeout(async () => {
        await page.close();
        await browser.close();
    }, 60000 * 2);
}

file = fse.createReadStream(__dirname + '/test.csv', 'utf8')
function parseData(file, callBack) {
    Papa.parse(file, {
        delimiter: "",  // auto-detect
        newline: "",    // auto-detect
        header: false,
        download: true,
        complete: function(results) {
            callBack(results.data);
        }
    });
}
parseData(file, scripts);
```

The expected result would be

Scripts Downloaded

CSS Downloaded

...

...

...

url, reqname, true(for scripts) false otherwise

Answer (score 0):

just put them in different functions and pass the parameters to them

```
async function scriptx(){

await scriptDownload(page);
await networkProfile(client);


}

async function scriptDownload(page){
}


async function networkProfile(client){
}
```

but i dont think your doing it right , your trying to check for a event inside a function which also should be called

Comment: I tried this out, but not sure if this would work because, If I put the functions outside there would be a reference error.

For ex, If I put the scriptDownload outside, the page in _page.on_ is undefined.

Is there something else like waiting for an event to finish in scriptDownload and then execute the other function

Comment: you have to pass `page` as argument to `scriptDownload` function  ... hence `scriptDownload(page)`